# Is there a place to discuss free software project concepts

Tags: discussion, subjective, site-rec

I wonder if there is a place to discuss a software concept in general and its realisations in the free software community. My special case is some questions about OCR of books and I wonder if there is a place where those could be discussed. It's somewhat similar to the answer of question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28293/182579.

Usually things are focused on a specific pieces of software. I wonder if there is a place more focused on the ideas and goals behind. Then as a second step there would be the question where, by whom and in which specific project these things have been worked out.

In my specific case which just is an example it's about OCR. I would like to go to a site where all open source projects which apply this concept would be linked so that it would be easy for developers to get in touch with each other and so that it could be seen that a specific question has been adressed by no software yet or that there is a library in some other programming language that could be applied to fulfill that goal.

I posted my specific OCR questions on http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.graphics.ocropus.

I wonder if there's some sort of meta project collaboration platform where there's discussion about which projects already exist, implementation details, what's missing, etc.

So I wonder not so much about some personal discussions but rather if there's a place where ideas behind software are the focus.

As an additional thought or explanation:
When there is a problem to solve like: I have a book and I want to make it a searchable PDF. There is a lot of steps involved: Scanner driver, Scan utility, image format conversion, scaling to make all pages the same size and have the same border, OCR, overlying image an searchable Text, conversion to PDF

That's a lot of different tasks and they can all be done by different kinds of software. One monolithic, multiple small tools. I wonder about a place where the names of all the tools, even scripts and their possible arrangements are brought together. And where the gaps are. Like a mindmap or a wiki. Then one could fill in the black spots with ones own script.

I can't write a comment to my question because I don't have enough reputation. A site that goes somewhat into the direction what I'm searching for is http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code (just the general direction).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I have subjective discussions about programming?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/where-can-i-have-subjective-discussions-about-programming)

Comment: You can always chat in [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) about things on-topic and off-topic, but it is not a true discussion forum.